# Intellij IDEA how to add my own keys for code completion

Tags: intellij-idea

`psvm` + `tab` would make:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

And now I want to have `cml` for:

```
CommandLineRunner runner () {
    return args -> {

    };
}
```

How to add it in IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [IntelliJ IDEA Live Templates documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/live-templates.html)

Basically you can create abbreviations like that :

- go to `File ->  Settings... -> Editor -> Live Templates`
- Add a live template with the `+` sign
- define at least abbreviation and text template
- define the appropriate JAVA context

That's it.

Comment: `psvm` is in `other` group. so I `cml` and `ll` in the same group. :)